# Inbox unread since parameter not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, inbox

The since parameter of /inbox/unread no longer seems to work.

I enter a date after the creation date of the item currently unread in my inbox and still the item is returned. I try putting in tomorrows date (so there should be nothing in my inbox since tomorrow as it hasn't happened yet), and it still returns the unread items.

Comment: Hmm, I bet this is a caching bug.  Should have an update/fix shortly.

Comment: It's not caching bug on my end, I've tried different browsers etc, if thats what you meant? Thanks :)

Comment: No, it's a bug in our code; I think the `since` parameter is working... just sometimes bogus things are getting pulled out of the cache, so that the `since` code isn't even running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed now, we weren't properly considering the `since` parameter when fetching results from the cache.

In effect if you ever asked for unread inbox items twice, once with and once without `since`, you'd get the same result back until the cache cleared.